# Analytically tractable Ramsey model: how to solve ODE for optimal trajectories

Tags: economic-growth, dynamic-optimization, optimal-control, ode

In [Brunner and Strulik (2002)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165188900000786) the authors claim, that the solution of
\begin{align}
\dot c &= \frac{c}{\sigma}(\alpha k^{\alpha-1} - \delta - \rho)\\
\dot k &= k^\alpha - \delta k - c
\end{align}

is given by (see eq. 27)
\begin{align}
c(t) &= \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sigma}\right) k(t)^\alpha\\
k(t) &= \left[\frac{1}{\delta\sigma} +\left(k(0)^{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{\delta\sigma}\right)\exp(-\delta(1-\alpha)t) \right]^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}
\end{align}
if $\alpha\delta\sigma = \delta + \rho$.
I can verify the solution for $c(t)$ (see eg. this [thread](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/8257/stochastic-growth-in-continuous-time)). However I'm not sure how to solve for $k(t)$. We can plug in $c(t)$ into $\dot k$, which gives
\begin{align}
\dot k &=  \frac{1}{\sigma} k^\alpha - \delta k. 
\end{align}

- How would one proceed?

### Solution

With respect to Alecos answer we may solve the following ODE

\begin{align}
\dot z + (1-\alpha)\delta z = \frac{1-\alpha}{\sigma}.
\end{align}

The genereal solution is given by
\begin{align}
z(t) &= \frac{1}{\exp(\int (1-\alpha)\delta dt)}\left[\int \exp\left(\int (1-\alpha)\delta dt\right) \frac{1-\alpha}{\sigma} dt + C \right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\delta\sigma} + C\exp((\alpha-1)\delta t).
\end{align}

With $z(0)$ given we pin down $C$
\begin{align}
C = z(0) - \frac{1}{\delta\sigma}
\end{align}

which yields the desired result
\begin{align}
z(t) &= \frac{1}{\delta\sigma} + \left(z(0) - \frac{1}{\delta\sigma}\right)\exp((\alpha-1)\delta t) \\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad k(t)^{1-\alpha} &= \frac{1}{\delta\sigma} + \left(k(0)^{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{\delta\sigma}\right)\exp((\alpha-1)\delta t)\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad k(t) &= \left[\frac{1}{\delta\sigma} + \left(k(0)^{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{\delta\sigma}\right)\exp((\alpha-1)\delta t)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}.
\end{align}

Comment: I did not read the entire paper but it seems interesting. What I have remarked is that they make an assumption of constant saving rate (page 749). With this assumption, they can take $k$ as a "constant" term for  which allows to find an analytical solution for the differential system. Otherwise, it is not possible.

Comment: The last equation looks like a solvable differential equation. I think dividing everything by $k^{\alpha}$ and doing the following change of variable : $v=k^{1-\alpha}$, might help. This yields a first order differential equation that we know the solution of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differential equation

$$\dot k =  \frac{1}{\sigma} k^\alpha - \delta k$$

has the structure of a **Bernoulli equation**. We solve it by the following transformation steps:

**1)** Multiply throughout by $k^{-\alpha}$:

$$k^{-\alpha}\dot k =  \frac{1}{\sigma}  - \delta k^{1-\alpha} \tag{1}$$

**2)** Define the variable
$$z \equiv k^{1-\alpha} \implies \dot z = (1-\alpha)k^{-a}\dot k \tag{2}$$

**3)** Combine to get

$$(1),(2) \implies \frac {1}{1-\alpha}\dot z = \frac{1}{\sigma} - \delta z $$

$$\implies \dot z + (1-\alpha)\delta z = \frac {1-\alpha}{\sigma}$$

This is a standard first-order differential equation with constant coefficients. Solve it and then reverse the change of variable to get the result.

**PS:** The above requires that $k \neq 0$ everywhere, which is the economically meaningful case.